# assigning dictionary to key values

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Dictionary<int, String> loadData = new Dictionary();

// File contains a list of filenames say for ex. 5 filenames
foreach (var file in filenames)
{
    // I want to assign like this
    loadData[id]=file;
}
```

How can I assign `loadData(key,value)` in C# so that I can access like `loadData[5] = "hello.txt"`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You are using `new Dictionary()` which won't properly work. Use `new Dictionary<int, String>()` instead.

Second: Where does `id` come from? If it's just a counter, you can do the following:

```
Dictionary<int, String> loadData = new Dictionary<int, String>();
int id = 0;
foreach (string file in filenames)
{
   loadData.Add(id++, file);
}
```

Comment: I have tried it s working but at response i am getting this error   Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Comment: @Mazher That's probably because you initialize your dictionary using the non-generic constructor. I updated my answer using the correct dictionary.

Comment: i used as you described but still i am getting the same error 'keys must be strings or objects', my id is not counter variable i derive it from model

Comment: i am getting the response correctly when i use the dictionary as new Dictionary<String,int>(); why it is so!

Answer (score 1):

if `id` is just a counter you can use arrays and still can write `loadData[5]="hello.txt";`

```
var loadData = filenames.ToArray();
loadData[5]="hello.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var file in filenames) {
    ++i;
    loadData[i] = file;
}
```

This assigns the first item in `filenames` to `loadData[1]`.

Comment: I don't think you can access the elements of a `Dictionary` via index.

Comment: You can. C# isn't Java. The difference between `[]=` and `.Add` is that the latter throws an exception if the key is already present, while the former overwrites any existing value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `ID`, it's not a value in `file` but the item's index in the loop

```
filenames.ForEach(x => loadData.Add(loadData.Count, x));
```

This will give you

```
Key   Value
0     First filename
1     Second filename
2     Third filename
etc...
```

If I understand correctly, this is what you want. Or do you have a separate `Key` and want to access the dictionary by some sort of index (like a List)?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy.
You can use this.

`loadData.Add(1,"fileName1");`

Or You Put this line inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ToDictionary()` extension method...

```
int id = 1;
var loadData = filenames.ToDictionary(x => id++);
```

Comment: In this case, you do not need to specify  the value as it is the Enumerable's type by default

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it.

```
var loadData = fileNames
              .Select((fn,index)=> new {key = index, value = fn})
              .ToDictionary(x=> x.key, x=> x.value);
```